# How to find current users active directory group in C++?

Tags: c++, active-directory, adsi

How would I go about querying what active directory group the currently logged in user belongs to? Below I add the example code which is similar to what I want. In that code they use "WinNT" method to work on it. But I want to use Ldap format like this -> hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://10.20.214.74/OU=Vimal,DC=test,DC=local". Can anyone please help me to find the solution? Thanks in Advance.

```
IADsGroup *pGroup = NULL;
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
LPWSTR adsPath = L"WinNT://Fabrikam/Administrators";
BSTR bstr = NULL;

hr = ADsGetObject(adsPath, IID_IADsGroup, (void**)&pGroup);

if(FAILED(hr))
{
goto Cleanup;
}

hr = pGroup->get_Description(&bstr);
if(FAILED(hr))
{
goto Cleanup;
}

printf("Description: %S\n",bstr);
SysFreeString(bstr);

VARIANT_BOOL inG=false;
hr = pGroup->IsMember(CComBSTR("WinNT://Microsoft/SecUser"), &inG);

if (inG ) 
{
printf("already in the group.\n");
}
else 
{
hr = pGroup->Add(CComBSTR("WinNT://Microsoft/SecUser"));
if(FAILED(hr))
{
    goto Cleanup;
}

printf("user added.\n");
}

Cleanup:
if(pGroup)
{
pGroup->Release();
}
if(bstr)
{
SysFreeString(bstr);
}

return hr;
```

Comment: C++17 added a [filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) that allows you to manipulate and query the filesystem. There is a function called [`std::filesystem::current_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path) which might be of some use.

Comment: @oraqlle - Sir I can't understand the above method. Because I use the ADSI concept to implement the above task I mentioned. Can you please suggest any method inside ADSI to find the solution, or if you know any example code kindly share it sir. Thanks in Advance.